# Disable AJAX editor in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have a condition based upon which I require that the AJAX HTML Editor gets disable.
This code is not working:

```
edNote.Enabled=false; //edNote is AJAX editor.
```

Please suggest any other means to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that a custom editor can also be made where we can display editor according to our needs. The code and link are given below:

Code:

```
namespace TestControls
{
public class CustomEditor : Editor
{
    protected override void FillTopToolbar()
    {
        TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.Bold());
        TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.Italic());
    }
    protected override void FillBottomToolbar()
    {
        TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.DesignMode());
        TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.PreviewMode());
    }
}
}
```

Link: [Custom Editor](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/ajax-control-toolkit/htmleditor/how-do-i-use-the-html-editor-control-vb)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of disabling it, output a `<asp:literal>` in place of the whole editor.

```
<HTMLEditor:Editor runat="server" id="edNote" />
<asp:Literal runat="server" id="lit" />
```

in C#

```
edNote.Visible = !condition;
lit.Visible = condition;
```